# On what natural values of a, the equation has no roots

Tags: modules, parametric

$$\left|x+9\right|=\frac{x}{2}+a$$
$$$$
$$ \left(x+9\right)=\frac{x}{2}+a,\quad x=2a-18\tag{1}$$
$$ -\left(x+9\right)=\frac{x}{2}+a,\quad x=-\frac{2a+18}{3}\tag{2}$$
And i don't know what to do next?

Comment: Just use the conditions that must be on x on both cases, in case 1 that x must be greater than -9, similarly in other case. Use that on the value of x you got in turns of a.

Answer (score 0):

For $$x\geq -9$$ we get

$$x+9=x/2+a$$ so

$$x=2(a-9)$$
and we get

$$2(a-9)\geq -9$$ so we get

$$a\geq \frac{9}{2}$$
Can you finish?
So no Solutions for $$a<\frac{9}{2}$$

The other case:

$x<-9$ then we get

$$x=\frac {2(-9-a)}{3}$$
and it must be

$$\frac{2(-9-a)}{3}<-9$$
this gives

$$-18-2a<-27$$ thus $$\frac{9}{2}<a$$

therefore we get no Solutions for $$\frac{9}{2}\geq a$$

Comment: Can you continue please

Answer (score 0):

Discuss with the value of $x$.

(1) when $x+9\geq0$, then you have already got $x=2a-18$. By the assumption, we have
$$
x+9\geq0\Rightarrow 2a-18+9\geq0\Rightarrow a\geq9/2
$$
(2) when $x+9<0$, then $x=-(2a+18)/3$. Thus,
$$
x+9<0\Rightarrow -\frac{2}{3}a-6+9<0\Rightarrow a>18
$$
Consequently, when $a<\frac{9}{2}$, there dose not exist $x$ such that the equation holds.